# Servlet redirection issue

Tags: servlets, web.xml

I am having the dropdown list on html page. On submitting the form, i need to pass the value to servlet. When i select red color from dropdown While submitting the form url is framed as, 
http://localhost:8080/sampleapp/%E2%80%9Dcolor.do%E2%80%9D?%94lb%94=%941%94

Expected url 
http://localhost:8080/sampleapp/color.do?color=1

Html and web.xml entry is shown below. Can someone find the fix for this issue?

home.html

```
<form action=”colors.do” method=”post”>
    Select the colors
    <p>         
        <select name=”color” size=”1” onchange='this.form.submit()'>
            <option value=”red”>1</option>
            <option value=”green”>2</option>
            <option value=”yellow”>3</option>

        </select> <br>
        <br>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>            
</form>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>color App</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.test.ColorServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>color App</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/colors.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Servlet

```
public class ColorServlet extends HttpServlet { 
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.getParameter("color"));     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing is you are using wrong character in your html file for ". Replace ” with ". Change the options as below:

```
        <option value=”red”>1</option>
        <option value=”green”>2</option>
        <option value=”yellow”>3</option>
```

to

```
        <option value="1">red</option>
        <option value="2">green</option>
        <option value="3">yellow</option>
```

So the right html file should look like :

```
<form action="colors.do" method="post">
    Select the colors
    <p>         
        <select name="color" size="1" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
            <option value="1">red</option>
            <option value="2">green</option>
            <option value="3">yellow</option>

        </select> <br>
        <br>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>            
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone find the fix for this issue?

Basically you have two problems

1. you are passing string colors (and not numeric representation) as values to the option tag
2. this character `”` gets encoded in the URL when you submit the form in your home.html

To fix it, switch values in the options tag (green) and replace double quotes with the right ones `"` where necessary.